# Ruby on Rails Rspec: How do you check the current path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

What is the code to check whether a current path is a specific path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the variable `current_path`, as in

```
expect(current_path).to eq '/users'
```

Comment: Isn't this available only if you're using Capybara?

Comment: Nope, it's built in

Answer (score 6):

You have several options, depending you are in a controller or view.

In the view you can use the [`current_page?` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F).

```
current_page?(action: 'process')
# => false

current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout')
# => true

current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout', order: 'asc')
# => false

current_page?(action: 'checkout')
# => true

current_page?(controller: 'library', action: 'checkout')
# => false

current_page?('http://www.example.com/shop/checkout')
# => true

current_page?('/shop/checkout')
# => true
```

In the controller, you normally check against the `request.path` String.

Answer (score 1):

I used the assert_equal method:

```
assert_equal '/path', current_path
```